# Confusing moment with derivative of composition

Tags: calculus

Let $f(y)=b+a-y$. We know that $f'(y)=-1$.

Let $g(x)$ be some function. How to prove strictly that $f'(g(x))=-1$?

Comment: What do primes denote derivatives with respect to? If you mean to plug $g$ into $f'$, then there are no variables to plug into, so of course nothing will change!

Comment: If $f'(y)=1$ for all $y$, then it follows in particular that $f'(g(x))=-1$ for any value $g(x)$. So the only thing you have to prove is that $f'(y)=-1$.